# how to create UK map with states in d3.js

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am trying to create UK Map with different state boundaries showing. For that I have written the below code:

```
(function() {
  var height, path, projection, states, svg, width;
  states = d3.select('body').append('svg:svg').append("svg:g").attr("id", "states");
  svg = d3.select('svg');
  width = parseInt(svg.style('width'), 10);
  height = parseInt(svg.style('height'), 10);
  projection = d3.geo.mercator().center([-2, 54]).scale(1100).translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
  console.log(projection.scale());
  path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
  d3.json("uk.json", function(collection) {
    console.log(collection.features);
    return states.selectAll("path").data(collection.features).enter().append("svg:path").attr("d", path).append("svg:title").text(function(d) {
      return d.properties.name;
    });
  });
}).call(this);
```

But this code is showing the UK map without state boundaries. Can anyone help how do I create boundaries in that map.

Comment: may be the state features are not there in your uk.json

Comment: how to add that state feature or get the json where state features are available

Comment: I picked up from here http://martinjc.github.io/UK-GeoJSON/ but i dont know if its states.

Comment: The UK doesn't have states. Do you mean regions, counties...?

Comment: yes I meant regions,counties..